# Unable to initialize main class in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new for spring and try to write my first code.

Here is my DrawingApp.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle)factory.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.drawn();
   }

}
```

This is my Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle {

public void drawn() {
    System.out.println("Drawing Triangle");
   }
 }
```

This is my Spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="Dinesha.Triangle" />
</beans>
```

When I run the project it gives me below error.

> Error: Unable to initialize main class DrawingApp in module SpringDemo
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

I googled the error and try some solutions but nothing works. Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: can you put a reproducer on github ?

Comment: How do you launch your application? Is Spring on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you haven't added the spring jars correctly.

Go to the build path of your project:

[image]

Make sure you added the dependencies under the Classpath, and not the Modulepath:

[image]

Comment: Fellow flaggers, I consider this to be an answer, i.e. it is NOT link-only, though very brief when ignoring the links. Tudor George, you can ignore this,  it is a good thing. But you may take the [tour] and read [answer], just because that info is really good for a new user.